# PayPal Express Checkout connection. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: ssl, encryption, paypal, paypal-sandbox, tls1.2

I'm integrating a PayPal checkout to our current eCommerce site. Everything works as expected on my local computer, but on the Staging environment the connection throws the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: **The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm**

As PayPal documentation states that is required, we support SHA-256 and have G5 root certificate installed on the server (https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en).

The server runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the ciphers supported are Triple DES 168, AES 128/128 and AES 256/256.
If Tls12 is not hard-coded (see below) it throws another error: "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".

I'd be grateful if anyone can assist on this.
Thanks!

```
    public string SendRequest(string url, string postData) {

        var uri = new Uri(url);

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var requestData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = (300*1000); //TODO: Move timeout to config
        request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        string result;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII)) {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end we figured out what was happening.
In Windows 2008R2, TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are disabled by default in the registry for client connections. So while the server itself can accept the two protocols for incoming requests, outgoing client connections has to be enabled via the registry.

The change has to be done under Protocols -> TLS 1.1 (and TLS 1.2) -> DisabledByDefault.

So, it was a matter of changing those values, rebooting, and TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 should work.